# Daily Schedule in CrystalReports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a daily schedule in Crystal Reports to show appointments for the doctors in the clinic. Down the side will be the hours of the day starting at 7am until 5pm in half hour increments. Across the top would be the doctor's name. Each column would have the doctor's appointment lined up correctly with the time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should give some information more about your context;

### Solution

anyway follow this steps:

1. Write a query that returns *Doctor Name*, *Day and Time*, *Appointment*
2. Filter the query by the interested date
3. Create a `cross-tab`, putting Doctor Name in Columns, Day and Time in Rows, Appointment in Field
4. Summaryze Appointment on MAX (or MIN, other summarization report a number not real value)
5. Edit style to omit totals for rows and columns (you don't need I suppose)
6. Edit format for Day and Time (right click on the field), to show only hours (and minutes)
7. Edit options for Day and Time (on Cross Tab Expert) to Display row every minute (default 'every day' will show just 1 line..)
8. Enjoy your report

### Be careful

- Cross tab allows just 1 appointment per row
- If there's a time gap in the time coming from the query there will be a gap in the cross-tab (look at 16.00 row); query must be written in a way to report empty appointments.

### Sample report

I created a sample report.

[image]

### Sample query

```
SELECT  'Doctor 1' as Doctor,  CAST('2012-02-01 07:00:00' AS DATETIME) as DateTime , 'mr. Red' as Appointment
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 07:30:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Pink' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. White' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 08:30:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Yellow' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 09:00:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Green' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 09:30:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Gray' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 1' , CAST('2012-02-01 16:00:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Purple'
union
SELECT 'Doctor 2' , CAST('2012-02-01 07:30:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Red' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 2' , CAST('2012-02-01 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Orange' 
union
SELECT 'Doctor 3' , CAST('2012-02-01 09:30:00' AS DATETIME)  , 'mr. Blue'
```

Comment: Hi Emanuele, I tried to do that, but It isn't working with me, whenever I insert a string in the summary field tab, they only give me one option and this is to calculate the count and I don't want that, plus I can't download the file you uploaded

Comment: Link is down, i removed it from the answer. You don't have to insert a "summary field" inside the report: step 6 is about Summerize inside Cross Tab expert

Answer (score 0):

#Emanuele's proposal works, but with a lot of restrictions: only hours and half hours within a fixed schedule defined at the report level are manageable!

My proposal will be a little bit more complex:

- Add a 'standard schedule' table in the database, whith entries such as these proposed by #Emanuele: from 7h00 to 18h00 with half hours.
- Manage a 'open schedule' table where appointments can be freely given at any time during the day: full hours, half hours, but also any specific time within, before of after the standard schedule.
- Build the schedule query by merging both 'standard' and 'open' schedules with the UNION operator

Using this method, it is possible to generate a report that will include

- the standard/empty schedule as default report
- all appointments made within this schedule, and this even if they do not respect the 30' step rule.
- multiple appointments for one doctor
- all appointments done outside the schedule *if they exist*.